# Find the integral of $\int^2_{-2} \frac{1}{4+x^2}dx $ If we substitute $ x = \frac{1}{t}$ will the answer be same....

Tags: integration

Find the integral of $\int^2_{-2} \frac{1}{4+x^2}dx $ If we substitute $ x = \frac{1}{t}$  will the answer be same if not give reasons.

My approach :

$\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx = \frac{1}{a}tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}$

By using this answer is : $[\frac{1}{2}tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}]^2_{-2} $ so answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ But if we substitute x = $\frac{1}{t} $ we are getting answer $\frac{-\pi}{4}$ please help why it is so..

Comment: Did you take into account that the substitution $t=1/x$ maps the interval $(0,2]$ to $[1/2,\infty)$ and similarly $[-2,0)$ to $(-\infty,-1/2]$? Also observe that the upper/lower boundaries trade places.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to work through such a substitution, but here's one of them: $$\int_{-2}^2\frac{dx}{4+x^2}=2\int_0^2\frac{dx}{4+x^2}=\frac12\int_\frac12^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2+\frac14}=\left[\arctan 2t\right]_\frac12^\infty=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$The first $=$ uses the fact the integrand is even, while the second uses $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_{1/a}^{1/b}f\left(\frac1t\right)\frac{-dt}{t^2}=\int_{1/b}^{1/a}\frac{1}{t^2}f\left(\frac1t\right)dt$$ for $0<a<b$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{1}{4+x^2}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$$ and Substitute $$t=\frac{x}{2}$$